# Having problems implementing Holt Winters using hardPredictions

Tags: python-3.x

I am using HoltWinters model for forecasting wind speed. HoltWinters is from hardPrediction library. When I am assigning model = HoltWinters(), getting below error

> AttributeError: 'HoltWinters' object has no attribute 'seasonal'

### Initial portion of the code looks like this.

```
from hardPredictions.base_model import base_model

from hardPredictions.extras import *
from sklearn.utils import resample

class HoltWinters(base_model):
    """ HW """

    def __init__(self, alpha=None, beta=None, gamma=None, seasonal='additive'):

        self.alpha = alpha
        self.beta = beta
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.seasonal = seasonal
        self.fit_model = 'fit'

        """ Checks parameters """
```

seasonal attribute is defined and assigned value from input parameters.

Please help to let us know if there is any missing part of the code.